# Poison Messages MSMQ 3.0 - WCF MSMQIntegrationBinding - Strange Issue

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I am having a transactional MSMQ with WCF MSMQIntegrationBinding listening to it. I am doing poison message handling via IerrorHandler.

As per the text, When a poison message occurs, it will fault the underlying channel and mark the message as poison queue. I am moving the message out of posion quque in IErrorHandler.

I am seeing something. When I set configuration
Retrycount = 1 retryCycledelay = 0. The message is moved to poison queue on error but it doesnt fault the channel. Subsequent messgaes in the queue are processed.

But when i keep configuratiion, Retrycount =1 retrycycledelay = 00:00:30 (30s) the message is moved to poison queue and underlying channel is FAULTED. No process of further message happnes.

Why is the channe only faulted in second case? 
Note: I have not given Maxretrycycle in both cases.

Thanks Rakesh